# nested struct initialization literals

Tags: struct, go, nested, literals

How can I do this:

```
type A struct {
    MemberA string
}

type B struct {
    A A
    MemberB string
}
```

...

```
b := B {
    MemberA: "test1",
    MemberB: "test2",
}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
```

Compiling that gives me: "unknown B field 'MemberA' in struct literal"

How can I initialize MemberA (from the "parent" struct) when I provide literal struct member values like this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

While initialization the anonymous struct is only known under its type name (in your case `A`).
The members and functions associated with the struct are only exported to the outside after the
instance exists.

You have to supply a valid instance of `A` to initialize `MemberA`:

```
b := B {
    A: A{MemberA: "test1"},
    MemberB: "test2",
}
```

The compiler error

> unknown B field 'MemberA' in struct literal

says exactly that: there's no `MemberA` as it is still in `A` and not in `B`. In fact,
`B` will never have `MemberA`, it will always remain in `A`. Being able to access `MemberA`
on an instance of `B` is only syntactic sugar.

Comment: Perfect - yeah I tried `B { A{MemberA: "test1"}, MemberB: "test2" }` but that doesn't work either - looks like you have to treat the nested struct like a member as you have above.  Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

The problem is with declaring the struct A in B. Please specify the name along with declaration, then it works.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    MemberA string
}

type B struct {
    MemA    A
    MemberB string
}

func main() {
    b := B{MemA: A{MemberA: "test1"}, MemberB: "test2"}
    fmt.Println(b.MemberB)
}
```

Comment: _Declaring_ a field and _embedding_ a type are 2 different things. If you specify a name, that is declaring. When you omit the name, that is embedding. You are not answering the question, your answer is an alternative proposal.