# error: cannot use promoted field in struct literal of type

Tags: go

I have two packages where Package B imports Package A, like this:

Package A

```
package A

type Car struct {
    Color       string
    Make        string
    Model       string
}
```

Package B

```
package B

type car struct {
    *A.Car
}

func NewCar() car {
    return &car{
        Color: "red",
        Make:  "toyota",
        Model: "prius"}
}
```

However, this gives me the error: **cannot use promoted field Car.Color in struct literal of type car** inside NewCar function, how do I fix this? Everything I have read online just makes me more confused.

Comment: Does [How do I initialize a composed struct in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123399/how-do-i-initialize-a-composed-struct-in-go) or [nested struct initialization literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325496/nested-struct-initialization-literals) answer your question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need:

```
func NewCar() *car {
    return &car{ &A.Car{
        Color: "red",
        Make:  "toyota",
        Model: "prius",
    }}
}
```

---

See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9859 for:

> proposal: spec: direct reference to embedded fields in struct literals